# A square pool is surrounded by a concrete deck

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, area

A square pool of area $144 \, \text{m}^2$ is surrounded by a concrete deck of area $25 \, \text{m}^2$. What is the perimeter of the outside of the deck?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to calculate a perimeter of pool and deck. It's 48 and 20. And then 48-20-18. But the right answer is 52. How?

Comment: http://www.douglascollege.ca/~/media/0171B78E56C44F138E0CB88CCD1B9F11.ashx

it's 14 task

Comment: Beech, please make a drawing of a pool _surrounded_ by a deck. The deck goes _around_ the pool. You can walk on the deck around the whole of the pool.

Comment: What is interesting about this question as it is presently posed is that the answer cannot be uniquely determined:  we are not told of the actual geometry of the deck relative to the pool, so its perimeter cannot be exactly determined.  Indeed, a fractal boundary for the deck could give us as large a perimeter as we please.

Comment: yes, and that was a problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the side of square pool $=\sqrt{144\ M^2}=12\ M$

Assuming the deck to be also square,

if the side the deck is $a\ M,$ the area of the deck with the pool $=a^2\ M^2$

So, the area of the deck $=(a^2-144)\ M^2$

Can you take it home from here?

Comment: Didn't get it. It's 14 task. Sorry, the right answer is 52 M

http://www.douglascollege.ca/~/media/0171B78E56C44F138E0CB88CCD1B9F11.ashx

Comment: @fleech, So, we have $a^2-144=25\iff a^2=\cdots,a=+13\implies $ perimeter $=4a$

Answer (score -1):

the area of the pool is 144m^2. The area of the concrete area surrounding the pool is 25m^2. The total area of the concrete block and the pool is 144m^2+25m^2=169m^2.

Now to find the length of each side of a square that includes the pool and concrete.

sqrt(169m^2)= 13 m

Perimeter of the square is 13m
Formula for perimeter of square is P=4a

Formula for square

P=4a
P=4(13m)
P= 52m

Verify

12m + 2x= 52
x=20

Comment: Please use MathJax